# Show Date with DateTimePicker from MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, listview, datetimepicker

I'm at the moment having a problem with my program I want to retrieve the Date that is in MySQL DB to show the Date/Week/Year I choose in the DateTimePicker in my ListView but I encountered a problem and can't see the solution nor have I found something that looks like it:

```vb
Try
    conn.Open()
    Dim Reader As MySqlDataReader
    Dim Query As String
    Query = "Select * from farm.sales where datesale= ('" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "') "
    command = New MySqlCommand(Query, conn)
    Reader = command.ExecuteReader
    While Reader.Read

        Dim Datesale = Reader.GetString("datesale")
        Dim Clients= Reader.GetString("clients")
        Dim Bank= Reader.GetString("bank")
        Dim Revenue= Reader.GetString("revenue")
        Dim Total = Reader.GetString("total")

        Dim LV As New ListViewItem
        LV.Text = Reader("Datesale").ToString
        LV.SubItems.Add(Reader("Clients").ToString)
        LV.SubItems.Add(Reader("Bank").ToString)
        LV.SubItems.Add(Reader("Revenue").ToString)
        LV.SubItems.Add(Reader("Total").ToString)
        ListView1.Items.Add(LV)
    End While

    conn.Close()

Catch ex As MySqlException
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

Finally
    conn.Dispose()
End Try
```

The problem I'm getting is in this line `LV.Text = Reader("Datesale ").ToString`, which I assume its because of the format I'm retrieving but I can't find a solution can someone pls help me get to a solution
Thanks

Edit:

My bad didn't post the error the problem the program crashes and I get the error An unhandled exception of type `System.IndexOutOfRangeException` occurred in `MySql.Data.dll`

Additional information: Could not find specified column in results: Datesales

Comment: Ok, but you never got around to telling us what the problem is.  But it seems unlikely you have a column with a trailing space `Reader("Datesale ")`.  After that, if the dbcolumn is an actual date type, you should read it as a DateTime type and then convert to string for the LV

Comment: My bad there isn't a space there in the original code has to the problem the program crashes and I get the error An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll

Additional information: Could not find specified column in results: Datesales

Comment: The code posted cannot cause that error.  The code refers to a column named `Datasale` the error says it cat find a column named `DataSales`

Answer (score 0):

this is how I use listview. I hope this helps.

```
    conn.Close()
    conn.Open()
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblUser"
    cmd.Connection = conn
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    While dr.Read
        Dim itm = frmAdminMain.lvUser.Items.Add(dr("UserID"))
        itm.SubItems.Add(dr("Username"))
        itm.SubItems.Add(dr("Password"))
        itm.SubItems.Add(dr("FName"))
        itm.SubItems.Add(dr("LName"))
        itm.SubItems.Add(dr("Title"))
        itm.SubItems.Add(dr("Department"))

    End While
    dr.Close()
    conn.Close()
```

i used *lvUser.Items.Add(dr("UserID"))*
in your case, you used LV.text..

just change it to *LV.Items.Add(Reader.GetString("datesale")*

goodluck! :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved it don't know what the error actually was I simply changed the name of the variable and the name on the listview and it solved it 
Thanks so much for the replys and